# Give an example of a $4 \times 5$ matrix $A$ with $ \dim(\mathrm{null}(A))=3$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

In the following practice problem I am trying to give an example of a $4 \times 5$ matrix $A$ with $\dim(\mathrm{null}(A)) = 3$

Workings:

Since the $\dim(\mathrm{null}(A))= 3$ we know that the $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 5 - 3 = 2 $. Since rank means the leading $1's$. Would a example of a $ 4 \times 5$ matrix be:

1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

Sorry I do not know the proper formatting for matrices.

Comment: @ Irregular User any idea if this logic is correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the example you gave is true. In general a $4 \times 5$ matrix has at most rank $= 4$, which means at most the $dim(Null(A))$ is 1 (in the case where all the rows are linearly independent).

Now if 2 rows are linearly dependent, then $dim(Null(A))$ is 2 and rank $A$ is 3.

Also if 3 rows are linearly dependent, then $dim(Null(A))$ is 3 and rank $A$ is 2. (which is what you say)

\begin{equation}\label{eq13}
A= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x_1\\
 x_2\\
 x_3\\
x_4\\
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $x_k$ are $1 \times 5$ vectors. Let $x_1$ be linearly independent of $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$. Also let $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ be linearly dependent, then rank $A = 2$ and $dim(Null(A))= 3$. Many counterexamples you can have such as:

$x_1 = [a_1 ,a_2, a_3, 0]$ for at least one $a_k \neq 0$

$x_2 = [0 ,0, 0, b]$ for $b \neq 0$

$x_3 = [0 ,0, 0, c]$ for $c \neq 0$

$x_4 = [0 ,0, 0, d]$ for $d \neq 0$

Comment: okay so is the logic that 5 - 3 = 2 correct? or was that just lucky that it fell into the proper range for the possible ranks

Comment: Yes, the logic was correct.  It is an application of the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) which says that the rank (dimension of the image, or the number of 1's after row reduction) plus the dimension of the null space is equal to the number of columns of your matrix.  Possibly ranks are anything less than or equal to the minimum of the number of rows and the number of columns, but if you didn't realize why what you wrote worked, then I suppose you got lucky that you looked like you knew what you were doing.